# Inaccurate and misleading Easy Jet flight departure information board caused missed flight

Tags: easyjet

Recently missed a flight from Milan Malpensa airport via Easy jet to Luton due to incorrect and misleading information on flight departure board.
Stated flight was delayed by 1 hour and 20 minutes, more information at 17.40.NO gate number ever displayed
Flight was due to go at 17.30, waited until 17.40 went to departure area only to be told plane went on time!!!!!
The flight information board was never updated, no calls for missing passengers, in fact the security passport control officer stated you have missed your flight to Luton due to the incorrect information on the departure board.
All Easyjet can say you missed your flight, total rubbish so did five other passengers, totally refuse any compensation claim.
Any advice please?

Comment: Your only recourse is a lawsuit however the burden of proof lies on you. Weight the costs and benefits. It appears you have a bit of a case if five others also missed. You may want to check the carriage contract concerning what takes precedence, flight departure board info or original printed time.  Were you put on a new flight within three hours? If you were you have no claim.

Comment: The question is not phrased very clearly, so I'm not sure whether I correctly understand what exactly happened. Since the question is about misleading information, I think it's important to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the FIDs are often operated by the airport, not EasyJet, so it's possible no one at EasyJet knew what was displayed at all.  In which case, you should file a complaint or claim with the terminal operator.  EasyJet's large operation at MXP means this is something you will have to research.  However...

Sorry for what happened, but it is the passenger's responsibility to present themselves at the gate for boarding at the (original) scheduled time, or the time printed on the airline issued Boarding Pass, or perhaps the time displayed in the airline's app.

Advice: Always be at the gate at the original boarding time where you can get information directly from the Agents and evaluate the actual situation.

Comment: Ok, nice suggestion. And as the same nearly happened to me once, can you even tell use which boarding gate to go when the boarding gate is not given, uh?

Comment: @motoDrizzt Presumably (yes, I know) OP had a Boarding Pass or app in order to enter the terminal.  That would be the first source of information.

Comment: I don't know MXP airport, but in the UK (where easyjet has their main base)(s), it's quite common to have no gate printed on the boarding pass, and the gate number is displayed on the airport only very shortly before the flight. It happened to me more than once that the gate was started to be displayed exactly at the time boarding started, which is often later than the boarding time printed on the boarding pass.

Comment: Consider, all but 6 passengers somehow found their way to the right gate on time.  EasyJet operates from T2 at MXP with only 8 gates, most of which are in sight of each other.